# How do I find the probability mass function of this new set.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let X be a random variable with $\mathsf P[X\in{0,1,2}]=1, \mathsf{E}[X]=4/3,$ and $\mathsf{Var}[X]=5/9,$ how would I go about finding the PMF of the set $Y=|X-1|? $

Answer (score 0):

Let the probabilities of obtaining $0, 1, 2$ as $a,b,c,$ respectively, where $a+b+c=1.$

Then, we have $\mathsf{E}[X] = (0 \cdot a) + (1\cdot b ) + (2 \cdot c) = b + 2c = \frac43 .$

Likewise, $\mathsf{E}[X^2] = (0^2 \cdot a) + (1^2\cdot b ) + (2^2 \cdot c) = b + 4c = (b + 2c) + 2c = \frac43 + 2c.$

Then, $$\frac59 = \mathsf{Var}[X] = \mathsf{E}[X^2] - (\mathsf{E}[X])^2 = \left (\frac43 + 2c \right ) - \left(\frac 43 \right)^2 $$

Solving for $c$ gives $$ c = \frac12 \implies b = \frac13 \implies a = 1-b-c = \frac16$$

Then the PMF of $X$ is $$X = 
\begin{cases} 0, \quad \mathsf{Pr} = 1/6 \\
1,  \quad \mathsf{Pr} = 1/3 \\
2,  \quad \mathsf{Pr} = 1/2 \end{cases} 
\quad \implies \quad 
X -1 = 
\begin{cases} -1, \quad \mathsf{Pr} = 1/6 \\
0,  \quad \mathsf{Pr} = 1/3 \\
1,  \quad \mathsf{Pr} = 1/2 \end{cases} 
$$

Or $$ 
Y = |X -1| = 
\begin{cases} 
0,  \quad \mathsf{Pr} = 1/3 \\
1,  \quad \mathsf{Pr} = 1/2 + 1/6 = 2/3 \end{cases} 
$$

In other words, $Y$ is a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $\frac23.$